# How to wait for garbage collection to complete?

Tags: go, garbage-collection, benchmarking

I was wondering is there a way to wait for GC to finish?

Lets say I'm running benchmarks:

- `BenchmarkUnlimited` (Does a lot of work)
- `BenchmarkNumCPU` (Is affected by `BenchmarkUnlimited`)

The problem here is that `BenchmarkUnlimited` creates a lot of allocations, garbage collecting all of this takes time, but `BenchmarkNumCPU` is already running and its results can be affected by the previous benchmark.

Is there a way to tell the go program to wait for the GC to complete before running the next benchmark?

Comment: This scenario is unlikely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Go benchmark framework already invokes [`runtime.GC()`](https://pkg.go.dev/runtime#GC) before running each benchmark.

So there is no issue - you can rest assured each benchmark is started free of garbage from previous benchmarks.

See [`go/src/testing/benchmark.go`](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/go1.16.7/src/testing/benchmark.go#L186): (also notice the comment there)

```
func (b *B) runN(n int) {
    benchmarkLock.Lock()
    defer benchmarkLock.Unlock()
    defer b.runCleanup(normalPanic)
    // Try to get a comparable environment for each run
    // by clearing garbage from previous runs.
    runtime.GC()                                    // <========== HERE
    b.raceErrors = -race.Errors()
    b.N = n
    b.parallelism = 1
    b.ResetTimer()
    b.StartTimer()
    b.benchFunc(b)
    b.StopTimer()
    . . .
```

Comment: Then I wonder, why does the case in the book actually get affected if the GC already ran? Maybe it's because even though Go finished cleaning the memory the processor is still busy doing the cleaning?

Comment: Were you able to reproduce that with a recent Go version? Maybe the Go version the book used didn't have had that call yet.

Comment: Yes, I am able to reproduce it with go1.16.7, the difference between running the benchmark in isolation and running it with the other benchmarks is 105707577ns vs 137399625ns (On my machine)

Comment: And adding the call to `runtime.GC()` like icza suggested has an effect? If not, then it's probably not GC-related. I can imagine that there are many other factors like e.g. heap fragmentation, reachable objects (not garbage), CPU scheduling, etc, that can have an effect on performance.

Comment: Nope, adding that has no effect, I've added the code to reproduce this into the question description.

Comment: The difference is because go is cleaning up goroutines, I thought this would be part of GC.

Comment: "*The difference is because go is cleaning up goroutines*" - how are you so sure? And no, `runtime.GC()` only collects heap objects, you can see what it does [here](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/go1.16.7/src/runtime/mgc.go#L1126). Perhaps the question title could be reworded to smth broader, along the lines "*go benchmark runs affecting each other*".

Comment: Edited question to not invalidate answers.